# Export links, defects and test results from Excel to QC

Tags: import-from-excel, alm, hp-quality-center

I have a question about HPQC. I have the Excel add-in but it doesn't seem like I can export the links between defects and Test cases. Is there a way to export the links between defects and Test cases from Excel?

Also, I would like to know if I can export the pass/fail status of test cases using the add in? If not, I'm not a coder but I could a colleague. Is it possible to bypass the add-in and load data from code instead?

Answer (score -1):

Excel Add-in will not support uploading test results into QC from Excel. Excel add-in can be used to upload tests, requirement and defects.

You have to write your own code using Open Test Architecture (OTA) API's to upload test results to QC.  You can bypass the add-in if you have your own code to upload test results. OTA API documentation is available in the QC documentation library.